# How to insert the image file in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert the image into MySQL table. The HTML code is,

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            <label for="My photo" style="color: brown; font-size: 15px; margin-left: 10px"> My Avatar</label>    
            <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col l5">    
            <input type="file" class="form-control"  name="myfile" id="myfile" style="margin-left: 10px; " placeholder="My Photo">
            </div>    
            <div class="col l4">
            <button type="submit" id="insert" style=" height: 40px; color: brown">Insert Image</button>
            </div>
            
            </div>        
            </form>
```

and php code is,

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if(isset($_POST["insert"])){    
   $file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]));
  $sql = "INSERT INTO insertimage(MyPhoto)
VALUES ('$file')";
    
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
} 
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

After the connection to MySQL is successful, it is not inserting into the table. Can you fix this error?

Comment: try
`$file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]));`

Comment: No. It is not inserting with $file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"]));

Comment: you have to give a `<button name="insert">` and let me know what happens ?

Comment: Yes. It works fine.

Comment: @Balamurugan it works? and your image is inserted into database ?

Comment: Yes. It is inserted as BLOB[64-KIB]

Comment: @Balamurugan if it works please mark as my answer accepted please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
<button type="submit" id="insert" style=" height: 40px; color: brown">Insert Image</button>
```

to and add attribute `name="insert"`

```
<button type="submit" id="insert"  name="insert" style=" height: 40px; color: brown">Insert Image</button>
```

**Note:-** For inserting `<form>` data in database you need to add `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not want to store the actual image or BLOB(binary large object) data types in a database.
You store the path to the image instead, located somewhere on your web server.

So in the column "MyPhoto", you need to store the path to the image on the server. Something like this "images/unique_picture_name.jpg".

You can learn more about this on this link
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: where it will be located php.ini

Comment: It will be located on the server filesystem. Not sure what you mean by php.ini

Comment: If we save the path,we can save the images in our system only. How to update the php.ini in other systems?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by that. Do you mean how to display the image? For displaying you can just create a url to the image on your server if you meant that.

Comment: Yes. If we store the path, how it will retrieve the image from the other system's local path?

Comment: The image will be displayed by a url that points to the imagr on your sever. For example http://yourdomain.com/images/uploaded_image_name.jpg